# Models for 3D printing are sliced wrong, can't figure out optimal thickness

Tags: mesh, workflow, bezier-curves, import, 3d-printing

I have a 3D printer with 0.3mm and 0.8mm nozzles, and I am trying to figure out the optimal line widths for extruding some line art.

## Workflow

- I create the vector graphics in Illustrator, expand strokes and group everything as a Compound Path: [`Slice-test.svg`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38807092/Slice%20test/Slice-test.svg)
- In Blender I import the SVG, go to Properties panel > Curves, extrude to approx. 2mm height, then convert to mesh: [`Slice-test.stl`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38807092/Slice%20test/Slice-test.stl)
- I take the exported STL and slice it with Slic3r, 0.3mm nozzle diameter: [`Slice-test.gcode`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38807092/Slice%20test/Slice-test.gcode)

## Results

The first layer comes out wrong:
[image: First layer of Slice-test.gcode]

What's going on here. Is there something wrong with the model? I'm trying to figure out the best thickness and angle sharpness so that I can produce a bunch of extruded line art for making molds. I'm trying to avoid interrupted perimeters and fingernail-looking things at corners:

[image: Fingernail corners]

Also my workflow seems kinda slow for such a basic task. As a noob to Blender and total noob to Python scripting where can I learn about automating the part with the **SVG import > Constant thickness extrude > Mesh > STL**, so I can focus on the line art?

Comment: What printer are you trying to use? Does it support direct g-code upload?

Comment: [Robox](http://www.cel-robox.com/). Yes it does support transferring GCODE directly.

Comment: Have you tried Cura for slicing?

Answer (score 1):

I opened your Slice-test.stl file in cura, and this is what I get:

[image]

The first layer appears correct to me.

Since you did not provide the line art for your flowers, I cannot verify that with cura.